# I want to use the function "sam" in R in order to compare two spectra and detect differences, but I get an error message

Tags: r

I try to use a function "sam" in R, in order to compare two spectra and gauge differences between them, but R throws an error:

```
Error in adjust.for.mt(data, cl, var.equal = var.equal) : 
  The length of cl must be equal to the number of columns of data.
```

My data frame looks approximately like this:

```
 t     x1     y1     x2     y2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 3999. 0.0124 0.0132 0.0122 0.0113
2 3998. 0.0125 0.0130 0.0122 0.0116
3 3997. 0.0122 0.0131 0.0122 0.0113
4 3996. 0.0121 0.0136 0.0122 0.0114
5 3995. 0.0124 0.0139 0.0122 0.0122
6 3994. 0.0125 0.0141 0.0122 0.0129
>
```

I want to compare data from x1 and x2 using `sam(dt, dt$x1, dt$x2)` but I get aforementioned error. Even if I subtracted only x1 and x2 columns from the table dt, I would still need the $t$ column as it is the independent variable. So, what are the right arguments to use for the function sam?

Answer (score 0):

I cant install such a packages on my R, so by assumption, try this:

```
sam(dt,dt[,c(x1,x2)])
```

use `c()` to store the colums you want to use `[rows,columns]`

OBS.: `[,1]` menas all rows with one column, `[1,]` mean one colum with all columns